Access checking is performed as if in a context unrelated to T. Only the validity of the immediate context of the expression is considered
The following quote from paragraph 8 of C++17:17.8.2 ([temp.deduct]) is one of the basis of SFINAE:

If a substitution results in an invalid type or expression, type deduction fails. An invalid type or expression is one that would be ill-formed, with a diagnostic required, if written using the substituted arguments. [ Note: If no diagnostic is required, the program is still ill-formed. Access checking is done as part of the substitution process. — end note ] Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type and its template parameter types can result in a deduction failure. [ Note: The substitution into types and expressions can result in effects such as the instantiation of class template specializations and/or function template specializations, the generation of implicitly-defined functions, etc. Such effects are not in the “immediate context” and can result in the program being ill-formed. — end note ]

Likewise, the following wording template appears in the C++17 Standard only 6 times (std::tuple_size<cv-qualified T>, std::is_swappable_with<>, std::is_assignable<>, std::is_constructible<>, std::is_convertible<> and std::invoke_result<>):

Access checking is performed as if in a context unrelated to <Type/Args>. Only the validity of the immediate context of the <expression> is considered. [ Note: The {compilation of the expression,evaluation of the initialization, initialization} can result in side effects such as the instantiation of class template specializations and function template specializations, the generation of implicitly-defined functions, and so on. Such side effects are not in the “immediate context” and can result in the program being ill-formed. — end note ]


Is this wording the way the C++ Standard has to "mark" something as SFINAE-friendly?
Are these 6 SFINAE-friendly cases the only ones in the STL?

Specifically, the wording for std::tuple_size<cv-qualified T> comes from a DR with that goal, that is, to make them SFINAE-friendly. However, there is some extra wording before:

If the expression TS::value is well-formed when treated as an unevaluated operand, [...]. Otherwise, they shall have no member value.

I was wondering why this was added too. If it wasn't, and if I understand it correctly,  std::tuple_size<X>::value from the DR example would still not exist because that primary template std::tuple_size<> has no specialization for type X. Thus, it could still be a type deduction failure (...?) and SFINAE would still work?
Is this other wording strictly unrelated to SFINAE and only to state when there is no such member named value? Or is it closely related and indeed also necessary to achieve the SFINAE-compatibility?

There is nothing about SIFNAE in your second quote. In the first quote it is the first sentence that specifies SFINAE. You don't need to talk about SFINAE in order to define the behavior of the type traits. That they are likely implemented using SFINAE on a partial specialization is an implementation detail. They can also, and some very likely are, implemented e.g. with compiler built-ins.

For tuple_size the issue is not SFINAE in the trait itself, but whether the trait can be used properly in a template to SFINAE or otherwise decide on a type T supporting the tuple_size interface. It just specifies whether ::value exists for that purpose.

The "immediate context" and "context unrelated to" is to not allow different results inside a class with private constructors or a private value member. The text is supposed to be sufficently clear and unclear to allow different implementations, with the same result.

@user17732522 Regarding your second comment, do I understand correctly, then, that my third quote is the only thing that they added to enable tuple_size to be used in a template with SFINAE? I found curious that in the other 5 cases I mentioned throughout the C++ Standard, the committee also added very similar wording to my second quote. Another example, not in C++17, is when they made result_of SFINAE-friendly in C++14, and they applied wording similar to both above quotes (second and third): https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3462.html

@JL I don't really see any differences in the wordings. Could you specifically mention the phrases that you are referring to? They always say that 1. there is a test for well-formedness of the expression as an unevaluated operand, 2. that access checking is performed as if in a context unrelated to the involved types, 3. that only the immediate context is checked for well-formedness. Then there are also notes (which are not normative btw.) clarifying that the check can still cause side effects in the compilation state.

@user17732522 Yes, that is what I think too, that there are not so many differences, that is why I wrote the original post, I suspected that is the way the C++ Standard has to "mark" something as SFINAE-friendly.
Re-reading my previous comment: "third quote" is the quote from the original post that starts with If the expression TS::value... (i.e., quote number 3); and "second quote" is the quote from the original post that starts with Access checking is performed as if... (i.e., quote number 2).

@JL All of this has nothing directly to do with SFINAE. These are all just the rules by which the standard library ought to decide whether the type trait has a certain member (or what value that member has). That's all. Even putting SFINAE completely aside, these rules make sense: If the type e.g. doesn't support the tuple interface, then it would be weird if std::tuple_size<T>::value would still be valid to write (and presumably produce an unspecified value?).

Calling these specifications "SFINAE-friendly" is really only done, because the most common usage context to differentiate whether the type trait members exist or have a specific value is during some SFINAE. But with C++20 SFINAE isn't really used as much anymore. Now it is usually requires clauses and expressions, which are simply defined to directly check whether an expression (such as std::tuple_size<T>::value) is valid.

@user17732522 Thanks a lot for your help :) I focused the questions on SFINAE because the DR that added this wording for tuple_size (https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2770) explicitly says they did it for that purpose: we need to change the library to make the tuple_size partial specializations for cv-qualifiers SFINAE-compatible.
